# How to generate random numbers in CX CAS calculator in python

Tags: python, random

I have Python on my TI-Nspire CX CAS calculator (PyWrite) and wanted to program so that it would give me random numbers I don't care in which form (floating point between 0 and 1 or just integers) but I don't have the unix time or access to libraries. Is there a way to make it give me random numbers without first me giving it a starting value?

Comment: Without access to time or a seed, where is the entropy for your RNG going to come from?

Comment: Agreed about the seed, and as far as the actual RNG goes (if you're making one yourself), it really depends how much effort you're willing to put into pseudo-random numbers - you can easily find info on many different generators like an LCM, xorshift , etc. etc. rather easily.